# Group By Joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My database contains 3 tables: Sku -> Color -> Product (screen)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/100x6.png)

I have next query:

```
SELECT anon_1.product_id          AS anon_1_product_id,
       anon_1.product_name        AS anon_1_product_name,
       anon_1.product_description AS anon_1_product_description,
       anon_1.product_size_chart  AS anon_1_product_size_chart,
       anon_1.product_status      AS anon_1_product_status,
       c.id                       AS anon_1_color_id,
       c.color                    AS anon_1_color_color,
       c.product_image            AS anon_1_color_product_image,
       c.custom_cat_id            AS anon_1_custom_cat_id,
       c.back_image               AS anon_1_color_back_image,
       c.color_hex                AS anon_1_color_color_hex,
       s.id                       AS anon_1_sku_sku_id,
       s.catalog_sku_id           AS anon_1_sku_catalog_sku_id,
       s.cost                     AS anon_1_sku_cost,
       s.size                     AS anon_1_sku_size,
       s.prise                    AS anon_1_sku_prise,
       s.in_stock                 AS anon_1_sku_in_stock
FROM (SELECT product.id                    AS product_id,
             product.custom_cat_product_id AS product_custom_cat_product_id,
             product.name                  AS product_name,
             product.description           AS product_description,
             product.size_chart            AS product_size_chart,
             product.status                AS "product_status"
      FROM product
      WHERE lower(product.name) LIKE lower(:name_product)
      LIMIT :limit OFFSET :skip) AS anon_1
         JOIN color c ON anon_1.product_id = c.product_id
         JOIN sku s ON s.color_id = c.id
ORDER BY anon_1_color_id,
         CASE s.size
             WHEN 'XS' THEN 1
             WHEN 'S' THEN 2
             WHEN 'M' THEN 3
             WHEN 'L' THEN 4
             WHEN 'XL' THEN 5
             WHEN '2XL' THEN 6
             WHEN '3XL' THEN 7
             WHEN '4XL' THEN 8
             WHEN '5XL' THEN 9
             WHEN '6XL' THEN 10
             WHEN 'YXS' THEN 11
             WHEN 'YS' THEN 12
             WHEN 'YM' THEN 13
             WHEN 'YL' THEN 14
             WHEN 'YXL' THEN 15
             WHEN 'Y2XL' THEN 16
             END
```

I need sort my products by Sku.price before Limit, Is there some way todo it? Or decompose query and get the same data?

Comment: So put an extra `ORDER BY` before LIMIT?

Comment: @LukStorms Yes, or delete Order by color and add order by Sku.prise but before limit.